# filter dataframe from xlsx data blocks distributed here and there

Tags: pandas

I got a xlsx contains  data distribute here and there. I do not wish to edit it but process it by pandas.

In below example, we use the pattern (rel-xxx) as column name and the following 2 rows data as valid values, the same row or same columns maybe contains multiple valid data blocks.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [
    ["case1","rel-01","y2","rel-02","y4"],
    ["cas2",0,2,3,3],
    ["case3",1,3,5,7],
    ["case4","rel-03","y4","y5","y6"],
    ["case5",2,4,5,0],
    ["case6",0,1,2,3],
    ["case7","y1","y2","rel-04","y4"],
    ["case8",0,2,4,3],
    ["case9",2,3,4,5],
    ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'])
print(df1)
```

expected output:

```
      C1      C2  C3      C4  C5
0  case1  rel-01  y2  rel-02  y4
1   cas2       0   2       3   3
2  case3       1   3       5   7
3  case4  rel-03  y4      y5  y6
4  case5       2   4       5   0
5  case6       0   1       2   3
6  case7      y1  y2  rel-04  y4
7  case8       0   2       4   3
8  case9       2   3       4   5

:    C1     rel-01 rel-02 rel-03 rel-04   
: 0  case1  0       3     2      4
: 0  case2  1       5     0      4
```

Node: the casexx is different, so just use case1 and case2 as valid row names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'])

df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['C1'], value_vars=['C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'])
ind = df1['value'].str.split('rel-').str[1].dropna().sort_values().index
col = df1.loc[ind, 'value']
aaa = [df1.loc[i + 1:i + 2, 'value'].values for i in col.index]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C1': ['case1', 'case2']})

for i in range(len(col)):
    df2[col.values[i]] = aaa[i]

print(df2)
```

Output

```
      C1 rel-01 rel-02 rel-03 rel-04
0  case1      0      3      2      4
1  case2      1      5      0      4
```

Here, using [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), the rows of columns 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5' are expanded into one column. In 'ind' through str.split('rel-') the lines are split where they are. A digit is taken and sorted, deleting with empty values. And at the end, the indices of these rows are obtained. In 'col' we get the names of future columns and in 'aaa' the values ​​for these columns (these are the next two lines). Columns with values are created in the loop.